# Searching for item in Firebase Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a web based app using Firebase and I have a Firebase Database structure like the image below.  Take note that there will be more than 1 user, and more than 1 boxes.  Is there a way to search through *all* boxItems from *all* boxes for an item?

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "all box items from all boxes for an item"?  Perhaps you could give sample inputs and outputs for the query you'd like to perform?

Comment: Which language or library are you using to search through the data?  Angular, React, Vanilla JS, jQuery, PHP, C#, Python, etc?

Comment: @DougStevenson, box items refers to the boxItems key in the database structure.  What I want to achieve is that I have a search box on the page, then when I search for example, "No button", it would return me the ID of that box which is -LZIKYZFCZTaPp7U7x-Z

Comment: @ClosDesign, Vanilla JS

Comment: I think you could just use Firebase query to search into it. Take a look at the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query)

Comment: Yeah, you can do this.  Have you read the documentation on database queries? This is pretty straightforward stuff. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-queries

Comment: @oninross, do you want it to show up on final keyup/touchend or as it is being typed.  If it as it is being typed, you will get multiple IDs until the specific item is found.  Otherwise you would be like Google where you could have the person select the specific selection from all possibilities.  Similar to at country search or something.

Comment: @ClosDesign, im already thinking of how to create an autocomplete/autosuggest feature for the search.  If it can be done without grabbing all the data beforehand, that would be great.  I would like to show the available matches on keyup/touchend.